# Is the multivariate Gauss the only pdf incorporating covariances?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, covariance, density-function, independence

I am wondering whether there is another probability density function known to literature which is similar to the multivariate normal distribution in the respect that the pdf incorporates the covariances between all variables, it has the covariance matrix as a parameter or is in some way defined by other dependencies between each two variables.

However, it doesn't need to be similar in the respect that it has a bell shape, or that its support is unlimited ($\forall x : P(X<x)>0$).

I suppose copulas could fulfill these requirements, but are there any other pdfs which satisfy the condition?

I haven't found any in the literature I have read.

Comment: Your question, freely summarized, says "I know of at least one answer to my question [copulas] but I don't understand it so please give me some more answers."  What is left of the question appears to hinge on some kind of distinction between "some" and "all." Please edit your question to clarify it and bring it on point. Consider researching our site, which references many solutions especially those under the rubric of "stochastic processes."

Comment: How does my question hinge on some kind of distinction between 'some' and 'all'? Freely summarized, my question is "Is there a pdf known to literature (other than a pdf defined by copulas) that captures dependencies such as covariance between each pair of variables?" A dependency between two variables can for example be the covariance. A dependency depending on all variables can for example be $E[(X_1 -\mu_1)(X_2 -\mu_2)\dots(X_n - \mu_n)]$, which doesn't capture the separate covariances.

Comment: I feel that the first sentence of my post clearly describes what I am looking for.

Comment: Your final statement, "All I have found is multivariate pdfs which are based on some dependencies between all variables," appears to answer your question. Obviously it does not answer the question you have in mind--for otherwise you would not even be asking--but it shows that your question as written is confusing and needs clarification.

Comment: I have deleted that statement, since it was not necessary for the understanding of my question and seemed only to confuse people. If you would find it helpful, I could also just delete all but the first sentence, which fully captures my question.

Comment: That would indeed eliminate some potential for confusion. The question that would remain is easily answered by following links on Wikipedia concerning multivariate distributions: start, for instance, at the [multivariate T distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution).

Comment: That is indeed a good answer. I don't see a link on the [\[wiki\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_probability_distribution) to multivariate t-distribution, however. Thanks for the answer! Know of any more?

Comment: It's possible to construct infinitely many distributions set up in ways that have parameters that are somewhat akin to or are functionally related to correlations. The most popular would be the family of [elliptical distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution), (which includes the multivariate t and the multivariate normal), which has a $\Sigma$ matrix representing the dependence structure.

Comment: Interesting! By the way, also the empirical cumulative distribution function trivially satisfies the conditions, though it doesn't have a pdf associated with it.